# ms teams: random selection of users by tag

Tags: microsoft-teams

We have created a tag in the channel and we can mention people by this tag.
e.g. @code_reviewers tag contains 7 people, but we want to randomly select 2 out of 7 when using it.

how can this be done? (ms teams bot?)

Comment: Are you trying to at mention the randomly selected users? As correctly said by Jos Verlinde, Could you please confirm if that works for you?

Comment: No, we chose an other solution - gitlab

Answer (score 1):

Teams Tags are currently in the Graph beta
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/teamworktag

with this you could build something like :

1. OP types `@bot connect me to <tag>`
2. bot uses looks up  membership using
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/teamworktagmember-list?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http
3. bot selects 2 candidates from members ( randomly)
4. bot starts a new conversation between the OP and the 2 candidates

Answer (score 0):

Currently it is not supported.

Comment: This is technically an answer, but ideally some supporting evidence for it not being possible (other than your saying so) would accompany it.